# Find entire function with roots in $\pm \sqrt{n}$ and $\pm i\sqrt{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, entire-functions

I am tasked to find an entire function with roots exactly in $\pm \sqrt{n}$ and $\pm i\sqrt{n}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

---

My attempt:

My naive approach was to use $f(z) = \sin(z)$ as an Ansatz, which is clearly entire.

Then, $$f(z) = \sin(\pi \cdot z^2)$$

should satisfy the requirements for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, because $\sin(\pi \cdot (\pm\sqrt{n})^2) = \sin(\pi\cdot n)=0$ and $\sin(\pi \cdot (\pm i\sqrt{n})^2) = \sin(-\pi\cdot n)=0$.

Clearly, the roots of $f$ are all simple. So what I think is left to to is to find an function $g\in H(\{z = x+iy: x<0\})$ such that $g$ has no roots and
$$h(z) = \cases{g(z), \quad z\in \{z = x+iy: x<0\} \\
f(z), \quad z\in \{z = x+iy: x\geq 0\}}$$

My candidate for $g$ is $g(z) = e^{\pi z}-1$ which is also entire and has no roots in the left half-plane.

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{z\rightarrow 0- } h(z) =\lim_{z\rightarrow 0- } \frac{g(z)-g(0)}{z} =\lim_{z\rightarrow 0- } \frac{e^{\pi z}-1}{z} = \pi \\
&\lim_{z\rightarrow 0+ } h(z) =\lim_{z\rightarrow 0+ } \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}\lim_{z\rightarrow 0+ } \frac{\sin{\pi z}}{z} = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0+ } (\frac{\pi z}{1!\cdot z} - \frac{(\pi z)^3}{3!\cdot z} + \frac{(\pi z)^5}{5!\cdot z} \pm ....) = \pi
\end{align*}

which shows $h$ is differentiable in $0$. That should make $h$ an entire function with roots exactly in $\pm \sqrt{n}, \pm i\sqrt{n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Is that correct? Or do I have to do it differently?

Comment: It depends (in part) on whether $0\in\mathbb N.$ Some books define $\mathbb N$ as starting at $1,$ but more modern books define it as starting with $0.$

Comment: $\sin(\pi z^2)$ is a good guess, but you need to prove there aren't other roots.

Comment: And the root at $z=0$ is not simple.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Of course not, my bad. But I can do the same at $z=1$ instead of $z=0$?

Comment: Do the same what? $0$ is the only non-simple root.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews OK thanks, I'll try to prove that $\sin(\pi z^2)$ has no other roots. I meant that I split the two half-planes at $x=1$ instead of $x=0$. So I have $g(z)=e^{z-1}-1$ to adapt for it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing after "Clearly, the roots of f are all simple". $\sin(\pi z^2)$ already answers to your question.

Comment: @reuns Oh, because $\pm \sqrt{n}, \pm i\sqrt{n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is the same set of points as $\pm\sqrt{x}$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I don't get it, too. Just $f(z) = \sin(\pi z^2)/z^2$ will be enough since it has those zeros and no other.  Why are you trying to define the function piecewisely? And in that case ou need to prove that your function is continuous and differentiable on the imaginary axis.